# Failed to merge 2 accounts (Stack Overflow vs. Stack Exchange issue)

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I followed the instructions on https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge and it did not work.
I'll have my other account that I want merged in also post on this.

Comment: This is my other account that I want merged into the mpaulse account.  Thanks

Comment: "Did not work" how? Did you [follow all steps?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-logins)

Comment: I did follow all the steps.  
I log in to my main account.  I then went to my main profile.  I clicked on my logins.  It currently has my google credentials which are associated with my main account.

I then click on Add More Logins.  I click Log in with Facebook.  My facebook credentials are associated with the account I want to merge with my main account.  It then says:  

Switch Users On Meta Stack Overflow
 Facebook (xxxxx@facebook.com) belongs to another user (Matthew Paulsen)
You can log in as Matthew Paulsen or cancel to stay logged in as mpaulse

I click login and I am the other acct.

Comment: @Bart sorry I forgot to tag you in the reply.

Comment: Same problem here :-(

Comment: Had the same problem (login/cancel, neither merges), then did it on StackOverflow instead of StackExchange and it seems to have worked.

Comment: @JoniJnm this was fixed for me by using Stack Exchange rather then Stack Overflow. – mpaulse 9 hours ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thank you to @Karl D Aborg for the hint.  If I followed the instructions and ran them from Stack Overflow it did not work.  When I instead went to Stack Exchange and followed the instructions it worked successfully.

My accounts are now merged together.

Comment: @JoniJnm this was fixed for me by using Stack Exchange rather then Stack Overflow.

Comment: JoniJnm will not be pinged like this. You need to reply on the post where he has left comment. (e.g. in the question) :-)